# Is there a generalization of Galois theory for linear homogeneous differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, galois-theory

Yesterday I solved this problem from Teschl's [differential equations book](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/):

> **Problem:** (Paraphrased) Show that the change of variables
>
> $$v = ue^r, \quad r = \int^z p(\zeta) d\zeta$$
>
> transforms the equation
>
> $$u'' + 2p(z)u' + q(z)u = 0$$
>
> into the equation
>
> $$v'' + \left[ q(z) - p(z) - p^2(z) \right]v = 0$$
>
> *Solution:* Differentiating $v$ twice, and using the fact that $r' = p$, we have
>
> \begin{align*}
> v'' & = (ue^r)'' \\
>     & = [(u' + pu) e^r]' \\
>     & = [(u' + pu)' + p(u' + pu)] e^r \\
>     & = [p^2u + p'u + 2pu' + u''] e^r \\
>     & = [p^2u + p'u - qu] e^r \\
>     & = [p^2 + p - q] v
> \end{align*}
>
> which is what we wanted to show.

I cannot help but notice an analogy with the procedure for solving a quadratic equation (in characteristic different from 2):

> **Problem:** Show that the change of variables
>
> $$y = x + b$$
>
> transforms the equation
>
> $$x^2 + 2bx + c = 0$$
>
> into the equation
>
> $$y^2 - b^2 + c = 0$$
>
> *Solution:* We have
>
> $$y^2 = (x + b)^2 = x^2 + 2bx + b^2 = b^2 - c$$
>
> which is what we wanted to show.

Is there some generalization of Galois theory that makes this analogy precise?

Comment: [Yes, there is.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.121.2187&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, your link doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: What about [this one](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540442288)?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That one does work, thanks!

Comment: So, is $u \mapsto u \exp \left( \int p(\xi) d\xi \right)$ the proper notion of “shifting” for linear differential operators, analogous to $x \mapsto x + b$ for polynomials? This is reminiscent of the procedure for solving linear ODEs with constant coefficients by turning the ODE into a polynomial equation.